# Generating checkboxes with the jQuery Autosuggest plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm using the jQuery Autosuggest plugin to select multiple items (cities in this case) and I want to generate a checkbox for each selected city.

So far, I've modified the script so, that the name of the city (each city) is wrapped in `<span id="city_name">Name of city</span>`, so it's easier to get it. What I don't know is, how to generate a checbox like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="city_id" name="city[]" /> City name
```

city_id in this case would be the id of the city, which is currently in a hidden input, where all the ID's are, separated with a comma (681,215,78,), but I can wrap the ID into anything as well, if that would help the case (i suppose it would).
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**EDIT:**
I've written some code, that adds the checkbox for the first city, but not the rest. I also modified the plugin so the name is wrapped like this: `<div class="mestoJe City_Name">City_Name</div>`:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
            var city = $(".mestoJe").attr("class").replace("mestoJe ", "");
            if(!done){
                var test = $('<input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="0"> '+city+'</div>');
                $("#checkboxes").append(test);
                done = true;
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Also, [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and other functions will allow you to append an HTML string of an element.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, what code? If you're talking about the plugin, you can find it here: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin

Comment: The code you're using already... Or, a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: After actually looking at the plugin, are you wanting to add a checkbox to the selected elements so the autosuggest selected items will submit in a form?

Comment: I want to submit cities selected with the plugin, and id's of cities that were marked, with the checkbox. So for example, selected cities would be 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50, while checked would ne 20 and 50.

Comment: You don't need a `setInterval()` AFAICT; use the `selectionAdded()` callback handler to add the checkbox. This would be much simpler.